# Ionic 2: Error including component into a page

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-components

I've created a component and I want to include it in my page but is not working because a error messages appears

```
No provider for MyExample
```

I already added the component to the `app.module.ts` in the `entryComponents` and `declarations` sections.

**My example component** *src/app/components/my-example/my-example.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-example',
  templateUrl: 'my-example.html'
})
export class MyExample {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Constructor...');
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts** *src/app/app.module.ts*

```
import { MyExample } from '../components/my-example/my-example';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyExample],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  ....
  entryComponents: [MyExample]
})
```

**My page** *src/app/pages/my-page/my-page.ts*

```
import { MyExample } from '../../components/my-example/my-example';

@Component({
  selector: 'purchase-page',
  templateUrl: './purchase.html'
})

......
```

The path is correct because in the app.module.ts I can display the content of the component with `console.log(MyExample);` and it's working perfectly.

I'm using Ionic 2 RC4.

Kind regards!

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do in **my-page.ts** with MyExample component class?

Comment: You can directly use your component with using selector you have declared ie: `my-example` in purchase.html. In addition if you can show further code that might help.

Comment: I fixed it including the component within a @ViewChild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it including the component within a @ViewChild